# Update loop does not update application

Tags: macos, electron

I have a problem with automatic update of application. Updates resists on S3, and my application finds the newest version properly. But after update, it probably does not update application at all, and starts the entire process again:

Here's my code snippet:

```
if(!isDev){
  app.on('ready', function()  {
    log.info(autoUpdater.currentVersion);
    autoUpdater.checkForUpdates();

    autoUpdater.on('update-downloaded',function(info) {
      setTimeout(function() {
         autoUpdater.quitAndInstall();
      }, 100);
    });
}
```